# React-elastic-carousel arrows custom colour on hover function?

Tags: colors, hover, react-elastic-carousel

.rec.rec-arrow { border-radius: 0; background-color: rgb(208, 212, 216); }

.rec.rec-arrow:hover { border-radius: 50%; background-color: olive; }

.rec.rec-arrow:disabled { visibility: hidden; }

Answer (score 3):

In index.css you can do like below:

```
.rec.rec-arrow-left:hover:enabled,
.rec.rec-arrow-right:hover:enabled{
    background-color: var(--clr-primary-400);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px var(--clr-primary-400);
}
```